# A Question about differential equation and Wronskian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

which of the following is/are correct

> Let $p$ and $q$ be continuous functions on $(-1,1)$. Let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be differentiable functions such that $y_1y_2'-y_2y_1'=\sin 2x.$ Which of the following is correct?

(A) $y_1,y_2$ are linearly independent on $(-1,1)$;

(B) $y_1,y_2$ are linearly dependent on $(-1,1)$;

(C) $y_k''+py_k'+qy_k\neq 0$ on $(-1,1)$ for either $k=1$ or $k=2$;

(D) The equality $y_1y_2'-y_2y_1'=\sin 2x$ is self-contradictory.

$y_1y_2'-y_2y_1' = \sin 2x $ this is wronskian and $\sin 2x =0$ in the interval $(-1,1)$ , hence $y_1, y_2$ are linearly dependent in $(-1,1)$ 
therefore (2) is right and (1) is wrong what about (3) and (4) can any one help me

Comment: What do you mean when you say that $\sin(2x)=0$ in the interval $(-1,1)$?

Comment: Also, note that "the functions are linearly dependent" implies "the Wronskian vanishes". "The Wronskian vanishes" doesn't imply "the functions are linearly dependent"

Answer (score 0):

We have that 
"$y_1,y_2$ are linearly dependent" $\implies$ "the Wronskian is identically $0$".

The contrapositive is
"the Wronskian is not identically $0$" $\implies$ "$y_1,y_2$ are linearly independent".

In this case, $\sin(2x)$ is not identically $0$ on the interval $(-1,1)$, and hence $y_1,y_2$ are linearly independent. So A) is true, and B) is false.

Next, we invoke Abel's identity. If $y_1,y_2$ were solutions to the given differential equation, then their Wronskian would either be identically $0$ (which it isn't), or it would always be different from $0$. This is also not the case: at $x=0$, we have $\sin(2x)=0$. Hence, C) is true.

I can't see why the equation in D) should be self-contradictory. For example, we could set $y_1$ to be identically equal to $1$, and $y_2=-\frac{\cos(2x)}{2}$, and that would solve it. If anyone has any extra input to add for this part, I'd love to hear it.